# JQuery UI Datepicker: Making a clickable link

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datapicker

sorry for the bad English

It is necessary for me, that at click under the link (sample: [28 April 2010](http://null)), under it the **jquery.datepicker** opened

To use `<a></a>` instead of `<input type="text" />`

Answer (score 1):

```
<a class="date-picker" href="#">10/10/2010</a>

$(function() {
 function onSelect(date) {
    alert(date);
 } 

 function openDatePicker() {
    element = $(this)
    offset = [element.offset().left, element.offset().top + element.height()]
    element.datepicker("dialog", $(this).text(), onSelect, {}, offset)
  }

  $(".date-picker").click(openDatePicker);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In an MVC app, your code could be:

XML:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DOB, new { @class = "date-picker" })%>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOB, "*") %>
    </div>
```

Which would render as (this is what it would look like as a plain old .html):

```
<div class="editor-field">
    <input class="date-picker hasDatepicker" id="DOB" name="DOB" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

jQuery (presuming you have the jquery library and jquery ui libraries in the locations shown below):

```
<script id="script3" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script id="script4" src="/jQueryUI/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script id="script2" src="/jQueryUI/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script id="script1" src="/jQueryUI/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.date-picker').live('click', function () {
                $(this).datepicker({ showOn: 'focus', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: "-130:+0" }).focus();
            });
        });
</script>
```

In the above code, you have a number of accessory settings, eg, to show the last 130 years (for date of birth) and buttons/drop down lists to allow changing month and year.

You can find these settings documented at:
[jQuery Date Picker Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)